# How to determine max size of images I can safely pass to/from OpenCL kernel?

Tags: image-processing, opencl, d

I'm developing an **OpenCL 1.2** application that deals with large imagery. 
At the moment, the image I'm testing with is 16507x21244 pixels. My **kernel is run in a loop that operates on chunks of the image**. The kernel takes 32bpp (rgba) chunks of the image in, and passes float4-pixel chunks out.

Let's define one side of a (square) chunk in pixels to be the chunk size. That is to say, an **8192x8192 pixel square has chunk size 8192**. Of course, on the right and bottom sides we have smaller rectangular chunks if the image is not cleanly divisable by the chunk size. My code handles this, but for the rest of this post, let us ignore this for simplicity.

I am **trying to determine the maximum chunk size** that I can operate on in each iteration of my loop, as well as the optimal chunk size (which may not be the maximum chunk size).

For reference, [here is the information reported by the clinfo utility on my machine](https://gist.github.com/miotatsu/f57d3c9e7c8b0680c874). I am running my kernel on the `Geforce GTX 560 Ti` with the Nvidia platform using their proprietary linux drivers.

My initial naïve assumption was that I could operate on the max 2d image size.
However, this results in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` returning an error code of -4 (`CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE`).

Thinking about it, this makes sense to me. With 1 GiB of video memory, one would expect to be able to hold a single 16384x16384 pixel texture (32bpp), or an 8192x8192 pixel texture (float4). If both need to be cached on the card while the kernel runs, we could expect to use the following amount of memory:

```
   4 bytes-per-pixel * chunk size^2 (input image) 
+ 16 bytes-per-pixel * chunk size^2 (output image) 
= 1 GiB total video memory
```

Solving for chunk size we get

```
chunk size = sqrt(1GiB/20)
```

Plugging in the amount of memory reported by OpenCL (which is slightly less than 1GiB - 1023 MiB) and flooring the result, we get:

```
floor(sqrt(1072889856/20)) = 7324
```

However, a chunk size of 7324 still results in `CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE`.

My next guess was that we can't pass an image larger than the **max allocation size**, which OpenCL reports as 268222464 bytes for my card. Because my output image has the larger pixel width, it would dictate my chunk size.

```
floor(sqrt(268222464/16)) = 4094
```

Hey, that actually works! **Now what if we try to go larger? To my surprise, it doesn't fail**. Through trial and error, I narrowed in on 6784 as the actual max chunk size. At 6785, it begins complaining with `CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE`. I do not know why the max appears to be 6784, and I do not know if this is repeatable or if the value fluctuates (such as other state existing in the video memory affecting how much it can hold.) I also find that running with a chunk size of 6784 is a few seconds slower than running with the size based on max allocation. I wonder if this is because OpenCL is needing to perform multiple (expensive) allocations under-the-hood? <strike>I also noticed the "max size of kernel argument" that OpenCL is able to report (`CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE`). However, that value seems bogus. If I could only pass 4096 bytes in, that would limit me to 16x16 pixels!</strike>

So I'm left with two fundamental questions:

1. **How do I determine the absolute maximum chunk size?**
2. **How do I determine the fastest chunk size? (Is there a method other than trial and error?)**

As a bonus question, are there any **good resources** I could turn to for future questions of this nature regarding **low-level OpenCL-hardware interactions?**

And finally, I will provide some code snippets for peer-review; I would be extremely grateful for any constructive criticism!

- [The host code module (dlang)](https://gist.github.com/miotatsu/5dfc2a3104aeb2add3ac)
- [Wrapper that sets up the OpenCL program (dlang)](https://gist.github.com/miotatsu/82ea8bfdef82d0fad02e)
- [The kernel code](https://gist.github.com/miotatsu/040a2ec8c2dfdc101a57)

As always, **thanks in advance for any help!**

Comment: I have one small suggestion: add `assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);` at line 112 of `rgbtolab.d`. I know that the buffer should equal NULL if the memory allocation failed, but perhaps this is a bug in Nvidia's driver. Regarding `CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE`, the image object passed to the kernel is like a reference to the array containing the image. I don't know the exact internal form, i.e. struct or pointer, but that's why you can exceed 16x16 pixels.

Comment: @chippies If the error can happen in a well behaved program (an out-of-memory error is one such error), don't use assert, as they won't be included in release builds. Use the exception mechanism (`std.exception.enforce` is a convenient way of doing so).

Comment: @chippies thanks, I meant to assert that but apparently missed it! Regarding CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE, I don't know why I didn't think of that, heh; crossing out the relevent section in the post.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It's true that asserts won't be included in release builds. I made the conscious decision to leave all error handling out of my release builds (I even use debug blocks when necessary). Certainly, you could argue the merit of that decision, but that is getting into bikeshed territory (at least for this discussion). :)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your direct questions:

**1)** To determine the absolute maximum chunk size one can use for a single kernel operation, one must know what 'chunk size' is in reference to. For instance, there are five defined memory models in the OpenCL memory structure. One of which is the the host memory, which we will ignore. The other four are global, constant, local, and private.

To get any information about your hardware in regards to what it can support I strongly suggest going to the Khronos API docs, recorded at the bottom. There is a slew of meta data about your device that you can collect. For instance, there are queries for the max height and max width of an image in 2D and/or 3D that the device can support. I would also suggest taking a look at the CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE and CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS to define your work groups. There is even a CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE query that is allowed.

To point out your concern for performance is that the reason the memory size that is given to you for working with is the optimal largest size for a work group or item (depending on the query). What may be happening is a spill over of the memory into the global space. This requires more memory allocations across different workers, causing a performance decrease. Not 100% certain on that statement, but it may very well be part of the issue when you exceed the recommended buffer size.

**2)** To determine the fastest chunk size trial and error is not needed. In the book "OpenCL Programming Guide" published by Addison-Wesley there is a section on using events for profiling in the host application. There are sets of functions that are allowed to be profiled. These functions are as follows:

- clEnqueue{Read|Write|Map}Buffer
- clEnqueue{Read|Write}BufferRect
- clEnqueue{Read|Write|Map}Image
- clEnqueueUnmapMemObject
- clEnqueueCopyBuffer
- clEnqueueCopyBufferRect
- clEnqueueCopyImage
- clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer
- clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage
- clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
- clEnqueueTask
- clEnqueueNativeKernel
- clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects
- clEnqueueReleaseGLObject

To enable this profiling, when once creates a queue, the flag CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE needs to be set. Then the function clGetEventProfilingInfo(cl_event event, cl_profiling_info param_name, size_t param_value_size, void* param_value, size_t* param_value_size_ret); can be used to extract the timing data. You can then have the host application do with this data as you please such as:

- Write out to a profiling log
- Write out to the output buffer
- Load-Balance

By using this profiling information you may determine the fastest 'chunk size' via your software or analytically and then using a constant for that chunk size across the board.

**Bonus Question** Some good resources will be the "OpenCL Programming Guide" published by Addison Wesley, written by Aaftab Munshi, Benedict R. Gaster, Timothy G. Mattson, James Fung, and Dan Ginsburg. I also would like to say that the [Khronos docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/) have a lot of information.

**As a side note** You are running this kernel inside of a doubly nested loop in the host code... this kind of breaks the entire reason for using parallel programming. Especially on an image. I would suggest refactoring your code and researching parallel programming models for GPU operations. Also do some research on setting up and using Memory Barriers in OpenCL. Intel and Nvidia have some great papers and examples in regards to this.  [Finally, the API docs are always available](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/)

Comment: I'm confused regarding how the 2d loop would be refactored (in reference to your side note). If the image fit in memory, it would only iterate once. The code does as much as it can in parallel at a time via what I am referring to as chunks. The only other option as far as I understand the problem would be to get a GPU with more memory (doesn't scale), or to distribute the work across multiple OpenCL devices, which on this machine would degrade performance because the processor is a lowely single-core (not to mention that this would complicate the code significantly). Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: You are right, if the image were to fit in memory you don't need to care about this mapping and unmapping of memory from the host to the device. Thankfully, you don't need those nested loops and concern yourself with the size/memory management. After know how much the device can handle memory size, you can figure out the allocations you need when using functions to copy over the working set of device memory back into the host memory and vice versa using several host functions:
clEnqueue{Read|Write|Map}Buffer
clEnqueue{Read|Write}BufferRect
clEnqueue{Read|Write|Map}Image
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject